# xxd - how to insert a long text at a specific offset

Tags: linux, xxd

How can I insert hex datas at a specific offset? more than 256?

I tried something like :

```
echo "00054cc0: 16c65206...5656c6c652eaa" | xxd  -c 256 -r - myFile.bin
```

How can I do if I want to insert a long text or a text file here?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It's all about programing! It's modifying directly files from hexadump!

Comment: but ok I'll post there. should I remove it here?